# JMeter HTTP2 request error (Java 8, JMeter 5.1)

Tags: jmeter, http2

I have java 1.8.0_151 installed and JMeter 5.1. Trying to send HTTP2 request getting the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:138)
at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.connect(HTTP2Connection.java:69)
at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.setConnection(HTTP2Request.java:280)
at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:140)
at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:117)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
    at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client.lambda$doStart$1(HTTP2Client.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client$ClientSelectorManager.newConnection(HTTP2Client.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1500(ManagedSelector.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN must be on JVM boot classpath
        at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.java.client.OpenJDK8ClientALPNProcessor.init(OpenJDK8ClientALPNProcessor.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:77)
        ... 8 more
```

I have downloaded `alpn-boot-8.1.11.v20170118.jar` (according to my java version) to jmeter\lib folder and  added the following record to jmeter.bat: `set JVM_ARGS="-Xbootclasspath/p:D:\apache-jmeter-5.1\apache-jmeter-5.1\lib\alpn-boot-8.1.11.v20170118.jar;"`. HTTP2 request still cannot be sent properly. What I missed? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your steps look good, I can only think of 2 reasons for the HTTP2 Sampler not working:

1. Wrong path to the `alpn-boot` library, you can check it using [`dir` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) like:

   ```
   dir d:\apache-jmeter-5.1\apache-jmeter-5.1\lib\alpn-boot-8.1.11.v20170118.jar
   ```

   you should see something like:

   [image]
2. Check the Java version JMeter is using as it might pick up not the `1.8.0_151`, but the one which comes first in [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). In order to ensure that JMeter is using the correct Java runtime you can explicitly declare it in `jmeter.bat` file:

   ```
   set PATH=d:\java\bin;%PATH%
   ```
3. And finally you can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to print Java version and effective Java arguments, the relevant code would be something like:

   ```
   log.info('Java version: ' + System.getProperty('java.version'))
   java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().each {
       log.info("Effective JVM argument: " + "$it")
   }
   ```

   If the above checklist items are applied you should be able to normally execute HTTP2 requests:

   [image]

---

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-released-td5728631.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible.

Comment: I've followed the steps you'd provided and it does not work still

Comment: Step 3: the following line appears: '2019-11-12 15:19:58,167 WARN o.e.j.i.ManagedSelector: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!'

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread also:
[HTTP2 request sample crashes with Jmeter4, Java 10 No Client ALPNProcessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425375/http2-request-sample-crashes-with-jmeter4-java-10-no-client-alpnprocessors) .
It says here: ***In particular, the jetty-alpn-openjdk8-client dependency is invalid and not appropriate for Java 9+. For Java 9+, the jetty-alpn-java-client should be used instead.***

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use Java 8

Comment: I remember, last year, when I tried to make this HTTP2 plugin work it didn't support Java version lower than 9, only 9 and above. And they also had a problem with redirects in HTTP2